# Matrix 'conditional Logic can be removed' checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle

```
public static boolean isCompatibleForMultiplcation(final Matrix a, final Matrix b)  
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("a cannot be null");
        }
        if (b == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("b cannot be null");
        }

        if(!(a.getNumberofColumns()== b.getNumberOfRows()))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

I am getting a 'Conditional Logic can be removed argument in checkstyle for the following method. I cannot seem to figure out why... Can someone give me a pointer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is complaining about this part right here :

```
    if(a.getNumberofColumns() != b.getNumberOfRows())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Whenever you see yourself writing code like this you can easily replace it with a single line by just returning the condition from the if statement:

```
return a.getNumberofColumns() == b.getNumberOfRows();
```

This statement will return `true` if the the number of columns for a and rows for b are equal, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: @user1743622 It is pretty common thing for beginning programmers to do. Most IDEs will catch it nowadays (or checkstyle in your case)

Comment: Typo. Should be:
`return a.getNumberofColumns() == b.getNumberOfRows();`